# Check a variable whether it is set or not "globally" within a function

Tags: php, function, isset

I'm trying to make a function which will do what the following statements do....

```
<?php
if(isset($var)){
    echo $var;
}
else {
    echo "";
}
?>
```

I have done this so far....

```
<?php
function echo_ifset($dyn_var){
    $var = $dyn_var;
    if(isset($$var)){
        global $$var;
        echo $$var;
    }
}
```

but its not displaying anything when I run..

```
echo_ifset('message');
// while message is a defined variable.
```

Comment: may be problem here is that when I am checking whether it is set or not within a function it is checking locally. So how can I check a variable whether it is set or not "globally" within a function ?

Comment: I have mention error of your code plz view my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you work with a reference, you won't have any problems with warnings (or errrors, my PHP is a little rusty!) if the variable isn't defined:

```
function echo_ifset(&$var) { 
    if (isset($var)) { 
        echo $var; 
    };
}
```

Note the `&` before the `$var` declaration, this is the reference operator.

Then, you can just call it using:

```
echo_ifset($message);
```

This method is also great if you want to define a method to set a default value:

```
<?php 
function defaultValue(&$var, $default) { 
    if (!isset($var)) { 
        return $default; 
    }

    return $var;
} 
?>
```

Some extra reading material can be found at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: My pleasure :) as with every feature in PHP, it has places where it should and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo the returned value of your function:

```
function ifset($dyn_var) {
  if (isset($dyn_var)) {
    return $dyn_var;
  }
  else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

And then just use:

```
echo ifset($var);
```

Comment: this is going to break when i'll call a variable which is not defined since php doesn't call a function until given variable is defined...

Comment: I guess this depends on your PHP settings. This works for me, although I get a notice. Darkzaelus' answer works however.

Answer (score 0):

You have pass message as a string so does not display it.

You have passed like `echo_ifset($message)`. if message variable is already define.

Comment: The semicolon at the end of the if statement is optional. It acts like an empty statement, and as such will not throw any errors.

Comment: @Darkzaelus Thanks i don't know about it.I have update my answer.

Comment: No problem Harry, PHP has a lot of interesting features like that :) This empty colon thing is also common across other languages. That way you can do things like end statements with `;;`'s.

Answer (score 0):

delete one $ in the if statement:

```
function echo_ifset($dyn_var){
$var = $dyn_var;
if(isset($var)){
    global $$var;
    echo $$var;
};
}
```